# Why does C# use late binding on a COM interface despite referencing a type library?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, com

I have a .NET 5 application that uses a COM interface to get data from an external accounting system.
Since the fetching of the data currently takes 30 seconds or more, which given the small size of the data is unacceptable, I have profiled the application in Visual Studio.

I am seeing `InvokeMember()` taking up most of the CPU time. As far as I know, `InvokeMember()` is usually used for late binding, but I have embedded the type library .dll in my project. My assumption was that since I reference said type library, there would be no need for late binding. Why does C# / .NET still use late binding in the background even though I never call `InvokeMember()` explicitly? Are there ways I can avoid this late binding or at least rectify its performance impact? Most optimizations I have seen are directed towards use cases where you do actually call `InvokeMember()` directly in code, which I never do.

*Additional information:*
If I look at the metadata from the type library, I see

```
[Guid("276EF2E0-E21B-11CE-AB56-00608CDFDCF8")]
[InterfaceType(2)]
[TypeLibType(4096)]
```

at the top of each class (with the Guid being different). Looking up the Guid in the registry then leads to my type library via a `ProxyStubClsid32`.

Comment: [InterfaceType(2)] is the problem, that's equivalent to [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)].  Nothing the CLR can do but late bind.

Comment: To see if this is caused by the type library definition or a limitation of .NET5, decompile the type library with OleView.exe, File > View Typelib command.

Comment: @HansPassant I have decompiled the type library using OleViewDotNet and I do not see the `[InterfaceType(2)]` annotation there. I assume this means this is a limitation of .NET5. Is there a way to work around this limitation? Can I use some optimization method usually used for "normal" late bind scenarios in such a case?